# The link between JS files and native side in Phonegap Application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i work on phonegap application and i am a mobile beginner developer. i have a problem when calling a `service` from the corodova.exec() function how said that there is no plugin (service) by the service requested :

```
D/PluginManager(1659): exec() call to unknown plugin: Plugin
```

note that :

- i use cordova.3.0.0
- i added this line in my res/xml/config.xml file : `<plugin name="Plugin" value="com.mwa.GCMPlugin" />`
- the name of java file is `GCMPlugin.java`
- in `GCMPlugin.js` i call exec() function  :

  GCM.prototype.register = function(senderID, eventCallback, successCallback, failureCallback) {

  ```
    if ( typeof eventCallback != "string") {
      var e = new Array();
      e.msg = 'eventCallback must be a STRING name of the routine';
      e.rc = -1;
      failureCallback( e );
      return;
    }

    return Cordova.exec(successCallback,failureCallback,'Plugin','register',
                [{ senderID: senderID, ecb : eventCallback }]);
  };
  ```

i don't know if i forgot something to add or that if i missed something else ?

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it :D :

we have to replace this line in the config.xml :

```
<plugins>
    <plugin name="Plugin" value="com.mwa.GCMPlugin" />
<plugins>
```

by :

```
<feature name="GCMPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.mwa.GCMPlugin" />
    </feature>
```

because we have upgraded the application to `cordova-3.0.0` so we have to change the plugin declaration syntax in the `res/xml/config.xml`